# Remove default "category" taxonomy from custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy-terms

I've created a custom post type called `Resources`. I want this post type to support the following custom taxonomies:

- Subject
- Type
- Sector

And I have registered the post type accordingly:

```
register_post_type(
    'resources',
    tp_build_post_args(
        'resources', 'Resource', 'Resources',
        array(
            'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-welcome-write-blog',
            'menu_position' => 20,
            'has_archive'   => true,
            'public'      => true,
            'supports' => array('editor', 'title','author','thumbnail', 'revisions'),
            'taxonomies' => array('sector', 'subject', 'type')
            //'rewrite' => array ( 'slug' => 'resources', 'with_front' => false )
        )
    )
);
```

And have defined the resources taxonomy like so:

```
register_taxonomy(  
    'resource', 
    'resources', 
    // 'labels'   => array(
    //     'name'          => 'Resource Categories',
    //     'singular_name' => 'Resource Category',
    // ),
    array(  
        'hierarchical' => true,  
        'query_var' => true,
    )  
);
```

And this outputs the following in WordPress backend:

[image]

I do not want the `categories` option, is there a way to remove this? I know if no label is defined for when running `register_taxonomy`, then "categories" is the default output. But I do not want a label to replace it, I don't want it (just want to see subject, type and sector).

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, removing the default taxonomy from custom post type in wordpress is not too hard.

Just change your code with this:

```
register_taxonomy(  
    'resource', 
    'resources', 
    array(  
        'hierarchical' => true,  
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_in_quick_edit'         => false,
        'meta_box_cb'                => false,
    )  
);
```

show_ui = false, removes the metabox from admin menu, quick edit screen and edit screen. You can hide meta box and ui in quick edit.